# mean of elements i and i+1 in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Out of curiosity, is there a specific numpy function to do the following (which would supposedly be faster):

```
a = np.array((0,2,4))
b = np.zeros(len(a) - 1)
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] = a[i:i+2].mean()

print(b)
#prints [1,3]
```

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
b = (a[1:] + a[:-1]) / 2.
```

to avoid the Python loop.

Comment: Neat, I like it :-) I guess I have not worked with numpy for too long! Thank you!